# How to make an iproute2 bridge setup permanent?

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox, network-interface, bridge, iproute

I've set up an archlinux inside a Oracle Virtual Box. To be able to reach the VM from the LAN I have added a bridge adapter and configured the guest system following the instructions from the Arch Linux Wiki: [Network bridge | With iproute2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_bridge#With_iproute2).

I used the following commands to successfully set up the network:

```
ip link add name lan_bridge type bridge
ip link set lan_bridge up
ip link enp0s8 up
ip link set enp0s8 master lan_bridge
systemctl start dhcpcd@lan_bridge
```

After those steps I'm able to login into the guest via SSH. Trying to make the changes persistent using:

```
systemctl enable dhcpcd@lan_bridge
```

does not work, though. I'd like systemd to create the exact same setup on startup automatically. Of course I could just paste those commands into a shell script and run it at startup, but I think there should be a proper way to do so. Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `netctl` in arch. First of all you need to:

```
cp /etc/netctl/examples/bridge /etc/netctl
```

Set your desired slaves in the line which says:

```
BindsToInterfaces=(eth0 eth1 tap0)
```

Last you want to enable netctl@.service like this:

```
systemctl enable netctl@bridge.service
```

Note: the name after the @ should match to your file name in /etc/netctl